# ASP.NET FormsAuthentication does not use State Server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

I would like to use State Server for sessionState. 
This works fine for all session variables but not for authentication. What must I do to store authentication in State Server so I can use a farm of Webservers? My web.config looks like..

```
 <system.web>
<authentication mode="Forms">      
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="20" slidingExpiration="true" />      
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>

<sessionState mode="StateServer" stateConnectionString="tcpip=localhost:42424" cookieless="false" timeout="20" />
<machineKey validationKey="F2FCB9C6C8F045A198D4885C6E...
```

Comment: Have you tried to used state server configuration for session and try to authenticate user. It should  work without issues. Only thing to make sure is that machinekey for all the machine in the web farm is same.

Answer (score 1):

I'm unclear about what you mean by "store authentication in State Server".

Authentication Is never stored in session variables, and it's a poor practice to do so.  Authentication is stored on the users local computer in the form of an encrypted cookie (either non-persistent or persistent), and therefore is inherently immune to any webfarm issues so long as your machinekey is specified in common on all servers.

Session and FormsAuthentication are to different systems in .NET.